# I can't enable mySQL on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I can't start mysql on xampp. here's the pannel config :
[image]

I tried to run mysql_start.bat but it told me that I couldn't find mysql.ini in mysql\bin. Is there a way to install mysql into Xampp?
Thank you

Comment: Check the error log for Xampp. You can find your answer here >>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322550/how-to-activate-the-mysql-database-in-xampp-on-windows-platform

Comment: @Kartik09 I know but I don't have any folder named data in mysql.. Only "scripts"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Vinod Kumar and @Kartik09,
I've uninstalled and re-installed XAMPP, the fact is Windows prevents writing permissions in "Program Files", that's why MYSQL couldn't work, I put the folder somewhere else ! :)

Answer (score 0):

There may be another running application in your system that is using the mysql default port '3306' number. Try to change the mysql default port number and test.

you can get help for change the mysql port number here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/change-default-mysql-port-under-linuxunix/

Hope this will help.....